# reason for last shutdown in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, shutdown

How to know what is the reason for the last shutdown action in Ubuntu 10.04?
means I want to track the reason for the last shutdown? whether it is due to temperature or due to the battery back etc.

Comment: Wrong site... you want askubuntu.com.

Comment: Simple: the reason is always `init` stopping.

Comment: @teppic This probably isn't Ubuntu-specific, and the OP might want to do this programatically.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin I guess. It just sounded like a general Ubuntu query.

Comment: I didn't get what H2CO3 is saying..

Comment: @Pristine: it was accurate but a joke. Is this a programming question?

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/114551/16521

Answer (score 1):

look at the system logs,this site I provided has all the logs you can look at such as  /var/log/boot

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-gnome-system-log-viewer/